# How to show a semi-transparent dimmed panel/image in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, vcl

I wish to get a TPanel or TImage to show a dimmed background (with a veil), anyone knows how to accomplish this in Delphi (2010)? I would prefer not to use a component if possible, just raw code.
The idea is that when showing a new form the parent one visually shows the user it's "disabled".

Something like this:
[alt text http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/1599/98002881.jpg](http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/1599/98002881.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the method that I use for my main form and then for all other forms that need the effect.
[http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2008/qt/form_dimmer.htm](https://web.archive.org/web/20150407084756/http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2008/qt/form_dimmer.htm)

Comment: This is why link-only answers are no longer acceptable. The link now redirects to something completely unrelated, thus rendering this answer useless.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066153/fade-all-other-windows-of-an-application-when-a-dialog-is-shown) can help you.

Regarding:

> I would prefer not to use a component if possible, just raw code.

You can instantiate and use components from code, not only in the form designer.

Comment: I know I can create components at run time but for such small tasks I always prefer to use raw code whenever possible.

Comment: What's the difference between "raw code" and using a component from code? :-)