# Dimming the screen with Delphi

Tags: delphi, screen

I am looking to create an effect similar to the lightbox effect seen on many website where the background of the screen fades out and the content you want to emphasize does not. What would be the best way to go about creating such an effect in delphi ?

The content I want to emphasize in this case is a movable panel located on my form and basically all I want to do is to fade out any area of the screen that is not directly under that panel.

Thanks.
Oscar

Comment: Lightbox uses an overlay whose layer is below the displayed layer.

Comment: Thats wonderful to know, but does not answer my question :/

Comment: Since I don't use Delphi development tools or language, I can't tell you, but that's how the JS library works in practice; it's an overlay over the browser window, with an element with a greater `z-index` "above" it with the content to display.

Comment: Unfortunately Delphi just doesn't work like that. Thanks for the reply tho, at least your tired.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Not being an answer is probably why @Jared made it a comment. On SO we tend to use comments to ask for clarification or give some information which doesn't answer the question but may be helpful to know.

Comment: Similar question: [Fade all other windows of an application when a dialog is shown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066153/fade-all-other-windows-of-an-application-when-a-dialog-is-shown)

Comment: I think Oscar should add a picture of what he wants, because this is a really vague question. I tried to literally answer it, and it's not what Oscar wants.  Oscar, please edit it.  Also please note that "under" is ambiguous in this context.  What does Under mean?  (Y position or Z-order position?)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50324516/282848

Answer (score 9):

Create a new form and add this code to the `FormCreate` method. You could also change the properties using the properties inspector, but I'm choosing to show you the relevant properties using code:

```
unit Unit1;
// This is a full screen partially transparent black form.
interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClick(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
uses Unit2;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BorderStyle := bsNone;
  Self.WindowState := wsMaximized;
  AlphaBlend := true;
  Alphablendvalue := 127;
  Color := clBlack;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Show;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;

end.
```

Here's a second form which has no border, which I am showing over top. It does not have alpha blending turned on, and the form style should be `fsStayOnTop`, or else you should use the `ParentWindow` property (on versions of Delphi that support that).

```
unit Unit2;
interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormDeactivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FAutoDeactivate: Boolean;
    FCounter: Integer;
    procedure WMUser1(var Message:TMessage); message WM_USER+1;
  public
    property AutoDeactivate:Boolean read FAutoDeactivate write FAutoDeactivate;
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation
uses Unit1;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.FormDeactivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Self.Visible and FAutoDeactivate then
  begin
    FAutoDeactivate := false;

    Form1.Close;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Form1.Close;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(Self.Handle, WM_USER+1, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TForm2.WMUser1(var Message: TMessage);
begin
 FAutoDeactivate := true;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BorderStyle := bsNone;
  Color := clWhite;
  FormStyle := fsStayOnTop; // or set parent 
end;

end.
```

That addresses how to make the whole screen "go dim", and then show something on top of that "dimmed area", but what you describe as "showing a panel in your main form" would require you to move that content out of your main form, or else clip a region out of form1, or use a combination of alpha blend plus transparency, but I don't have any code for those to show you.

If I was doing it, I would just float the thing I want not to be dimmed, above the full screen borderless 50% alpha form, as shown below.

But as you see, the screen isn't dimmed (screen brightness is not reduced), it's merely that we've done a 50% transparent layer of black which has blended in and darkened the overall screen appearance.

[image]

Comment: I already went that route in the past and the effect is ugly to say the least. I guess I should of phrased the question better. What I am actually trying to achive in an effect similar to the way the windows xp shutdown screen looks where the entire area behind the shutdown window is grey scale and faded out. I only used the lightbox effect because more people would know what I am talking about.

Comment: On that note however I have decided to go the cheap route and just do a screen copy and place it on my main form which is set to display full screen. I can then use sort of function that will apply a geyscale filter to the parts of the image that are not under my panel. cheap yes, but it works.

Comment: @Warren P: `"showing a panel in your main form" would require you to move that content out of your main form, or else clip a region out of the main form` – It is possible to use both transparency and alpha blending. That way you can have a 'hole' in the form that is used to 'dim' the screen (for example, by placing a panel with its colour set to the TransparentColorValue colour of the form), and that area would not be dimmed.

Comment: Okay, glad that this is possible (transparency + alpha blending) but I didn't have some code handy to do it, and so I did what I could.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same need as Oscar. After some search on the net, I found what is shown here.
It has helped me to do this, since it works. You can move what is emphasized in a Form instead of a Panel.
I use two forms. The first is use as "fader" and the second as dialogbox.
First

```
unit uFormFaded;

interface

uses
   ...

type
  TFormFaded = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Déclarations privées }
  public
    { Déclarations publiques }
  end;

var
  FormFaded: TFormFaded;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFormFaded.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); 
begin
  Align := alClient;
  AlphaBlend := true;
  AlphaBlendValue := 100;
  BorderStyle := bsNone;
  Color := clBlack;
  Enabled := false;
  FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;
end;

end.
```

Second

```
unit UFormDlgBox;

interface

uses
   ...

type
  TFormDlgBox = class(TForm)
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    { Déclarations privées }
  public
    { Déclarations publiques }
  end;

var
  FormDlgBox: TFormDlgBox;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses uFormFaded;

procedure TFormDlgBox.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  FormFaded.Close;
end;

procedure TFormDlgBox.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FormFaded.Show;
end;

end.
```

The use

```
FormDlgBox.ShowModal;
```

I tried to reproduce this schema creating the forms in run-time an make the TFormDlgBox Owns and create the TFormFaded but it doesn't work. It seems it works only with forms created in design-time.