# How create a "shadow effect" similar to " shutting down Windows"?

Tags: delphi

You know when we go to Start/Shut down how Windows "shadows" the screen's 
controls and windows, I don't really know how to call that effect... but I 
was wondering how could I create that effect in my application. Any help 
will be very welcome.

Here is a example:

[image]

Comment: It's just a window set to top most with an opacity (and also the inability to use certain key combos etc).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880651/dimming-the-screen-with-delphi

Comment: OK @SertacAkyuz, Thank you very much!

Comment: It's a pity this question gets closed; it's the better of the two. In fact OP of the other question still isn't clear about what he actually wanted... He just for some reason considered Warren's answer to be "ugly".

Comment: @CraigYoung, both QQ are of roughly equally low quality. He wants Windows XP effect.

Comment: @CraigYoung That other question seemed extremely clear to me.

Comment: Any another suggestion of code are welcome! You can upload in a external host, and I will see :-)

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works though. You've been linked a duplicate question, consuming an answer which fits your requirements.

Comment: @JerryDodge The other question ***seemed*** clear to me too; and based on OP's _description_, Warren's answer _should have been_ suitable; but OP of that question didn't like it. So OP's description failed to convey his requirement. A simple image (as in this question) would have been worth a thousand words.

Comment: @CarlosAlberto If someone has other suggestions, they will be added to the other question. Also if you think you might be able to get a better answer, you do have another option when you've earned more reputation. You will be able to offer a bounty on the other question to encourage more answers, and you can award the bounty to the one that best suits you.