# How draw a shadow effect in a complete Bitmap image?

Tags: delphi

I want know if is possible draw a shadow effect in a complete Bitmap image already existent and after have a effect similar to this example below, where all area behind modal Form is my new Bitmap image already with the shadow effect? =>

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is pretty easy. First we need a routine that fades a given bitmap:

```
procedure FadeBitmap(ABitmap: TBitmap);
type
  PRGBTripleArray = ^TRGBTripleArray;
  TRGBTripleArray = array[word] of TRGBTriple;
var
  SL: PRGBTripleArray;
  y: Integer;
  x: Integer;
begin
  ABitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;

  for y := 0 to ABitmap.Height - 1 do
  begin
    SL := ABitmap.ScanLine[y];
    for x := 0 to ABitmap.Width - 1 do
      with SL[x] do
        begin
          rgbtRed := rgbtRed div 2;
          rgbtGreen := rgbtGreen div 2;
          rgbtBlue := rgbtBlue div 2;
        end;
  end;
end;
```

Then, when we want to display our modal message, we create a bitmap 'screenshot' of our current form, fade it, and place it on top of all controls of the form:

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  bm: TBitmap;
  pn: TPanel;
  img: TImage;
begin

  bm := GetFormImage;
  try
    FadeBitmap(bm);

    pn := TPanel.Create(nil);
    try
      img := TImage.Create(nil);
      try
        img.Parent := pn;

        pn.BoundsRect := ClientRect;
        pn.BevelOuter := bvNone;
        img.Align := alClient;

        img.Picture.Bitmap.Assign(bm);

        pn.Parent := Self;

        ShowMessage('Hello, Faded Background!');

      finally
        img.Free;
      end;
    finally
      pn.Free;
    end;
  finally
    bm.Free;
  end;

end;
```

[image: A VCL form with a faded background when a modal window is shown.]

*Hint:* If you have more than one modal dialog to display in your application, you probably want to refactor this. To this end, have a look at `TApplicationEvent`'s `OnModalBegin` and `OnModalEnd` events.

Comment: i already have a `TImage`component on Form (not runtime created) and not use `TPanel`, then how apply this shadow only to stay above `TImage`and instead of `ShowMessage` show a `Form2`?

Comment: To display Form2 instead of a message box, replace `ShowMessage('Hello, Faded Background!');` with `with TForm2.Create(Self) do try ShowModal; finally Free; end;`. But this is Delphi basics, so you can read all about it in any Delphi tutorial.

Comment: not must `ShowModal`, only `Show` (normal). I tested showing normally,and shadow effect not worked.

Comment: And also i not need of a `TPanel`. Only `TImage` + `Form2.Show` + shadow effect behind `Form2`

Comment: @KKK: In your question, you specifically wrote "modal". Of course it doesn't work with only `Show`, because `Show` returns immediately, so the shadow removal code is executed directly. If you want to use a non-modal popup form, you need to move the shadow removal code to the time when you close the popup. Further, since a `TImage` is a graphic control, it cannot be on top of windowed controls. Hence the panel.

Comment: ok. I already have a  `TImage` component that store a screen capture, and also i have several `Panel`. Each `Panel` have a `TImage` with a picture inside. Like you said (and showed on code above), i mandatorily need a `TPanel` to `TImage` that will create shadow effect. Then exists some chance of my `Panel`(these that i already have here) activate the shadow effect when he appear?

Comment: Or..., simply, show a TRectangle with some Opacity before the dialog box

Comment: @JohnKouraklis: `TRectangle`? That must be a FMX thing. We are talking about VCL here.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Oh, ok. I didn't realise it was VCL question. It is not mentioned anywhere I think. Yes, TRectangle is a FMX component