# Make darker each pixel in a TImage

Tags: delphi

I have a TImage placed on my Form and set a PNG image into it.

Is it possible to change the opacity of each pixel of the PNG image in runtime? I want to change the opacity according to specific actions in my application.

I'm using the following code to make a pixel darker, the idea is to apply that function to each pixel in the TImage:

```
function DarkerColor(thisColor: TColor; thePercent: Byte): TColor;
var
  (* a TColor is made out of Red, Green and blue *)
  cRed,
  cGreen,
  cBlue: Byte;
begin
  (* get them individually *)
  cRed := GetRValue(thisColor);
  cGreen := GetGValue(thisColor);
  cBlue := GetBValue(thisColor);
  (* make them darker thePercent *)
  (* we need a byte value but the "/" operator
     returns a float value so we use Round function
     because type mismatch *)
  cRed := Round(cRed * thePercent / 100);
  cGreen := Round(cGreen * thePercent / 100);
  cBlue := Round(cBlue * thePercent / 100);
  (* return them as TColor *)
  Result := RGB(cRed, cGreen, cBlue);
end;
```

I have found how to access to each pixel in a BMP image. The thing is that I'm using a TImage with a PNG loaded in it.

Thanks!

Comment: Use the TImage.Canvas.Pixels property?

Comment: The Pixels property is *very* slow. Instead, you should use scanlines. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322714/how-draw-a-shadow-effect-in-a-complete-bitmap-image?rq=1

Comment: Thanks! I have tried with TImage.Canvas.Pixels but I got a Delphi exception "Can only modify an image if it contains a bitmap.". Any workaround?

Comment: @raff: Convert it to a bitmap, modify it, and convert it back to a PNG.

Comment: Not sure that `TImage` is the right place to be working. It's intended for static images. You are best loading the PNG into a bitmap, working on it there, and then assigning to the image control once you are done. The way you ask the question belies a problem in how you are approaching the problem. The problem is not how to make pixels darker. You already know how to do that. The problem is how to modify pixels. You need to start thinking about problems by breaking big problems into their constituent pieces.

Comment: One minor point of detail is that it seems wasteful to me to use floating point arithmetic here. You are looking for the function `MulDiv`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `ScanLine` of your `PNG`-image to make it darker before assign it to `TImage`component. It should be faster then convert `TBitmap` from `TImage` to `PNG`, perform actions and convert it back to `TBitmap` and assign it to `TImage` component again. Also, once you assigned `PNG` to `TBitmap` there is no way to get partial transparency of `PNG` back. At least, all my trying in past weren't successful, that's why I prefer to store `PNG`-files inside my small programs and change (sizing, blending etc.) *their copy* during run-time.

I changed your source code to exclude operations with floating point. It was replaced with `MulDiv` function.

```
function DarkerColor(thisColor: TColor; thePercent: Byte): TColor;
var
  (* a TColor is made out of Red, Green and blue *)
  cRed,
  cGreen,
  cBlue: Byte;
begin
  (* get them individually *)
  cRed := GetRValue(thisColor);
  cGreen := GetGValue(thisColor);
  cBlue := GetBValue(thisColor);

  (* make them darker thePercent *)
  cRed := MulDiv(cRed, thePercent, 100);
  cGreen := MulDiv(cGreen, thePercent, 100);
  cBlue := MulDiv(cBlue, thePercent, 100);

  (* return them as TColor *)
  Result := RGB(cRed, cGreen, cBlue);
end;
```

Now you can go further and use `ScanLine` of your `PNG`-image:

```
procedure MakePNGDarker(APNGInOut: TPNGImage; AValue: Integer);
type
  TRGBArray = Array [0..65535 - 1] of WinAPI.Windows.tagRGBTRIPLE;
  PRGBArray = ^TRGBArray;
var
  RowInOut: PRGBArray;
  SourceColor: TColor;
  ResultColor: TColor;
  X: Integer;
  Y: Integer;
begin
  if not Assigned(APNGInOut) or (AValue < 0) then
    Exit;

  for Y:=0 to APNGInOut.Height - 1 do
    begin
      RowInOut := APNGInOut.ScanLine[Y];
      for X:=0 to APNGInOut.Width - 1 do
        begin
          SourceColor := RGB(RowInOut[X].rgbtRed, RowInOut[X].rgbtGreen, RowInOut[X].rgbtBlue);
          ResultColor := DarkerColor(SourceColor, AValue);

          RowInOut[X].rgbtRed := GetRValue(ResultColor);
          RowInOut[X].rgbtGreen := GetGValue(ResultColor);
          RowInOut[X].rgbtBlue := GetBValue(ResultColor);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Here is a result of the job that function done.
*Fig. A* stands for original image; *Figures from B to F* are present gradation of a modified images whose darkness was set with step of 25 through 0 to 100.

*Note*
Edges of colored images are blurred as these images were made with blurred edges. This is not a result of function work!

[image: example]

Useful resources

- [MulDiv function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-muldiv)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great solution!