# How create shadow effect in pf32bit bitmap?

Tags: delphi, graphics, bitmapimage, delphi-10.3-rio, pixelformat

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50324516/17564313) code that works fine with `pf24bit`. How change to work with `pf32bit` (or any other `PixelFormat`)?

---

**Edit**:

For example if you get a screenshot, this code doesn’t apply effect in full bitmap width. To bitmap height it's ok.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to change the `PixelFormat` to `pf32bit` in the code you are referencing?

Comment: @EirikA.: That alone will not work. In a 32-bit pixmap, the scanlines are arrays of RGBA values, not RGB values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is straightforward.

A 24-bpp image has format BGR and a 32-bpp image has format BGRA, where the alpha component is typically not used for anything. To blacken the bitmap, we simply ignore the A component.

So, 24 bits per pixel:

```pascal
procedure FadeBitmap24(ABitmap: TBitmap);
type
  PRGBTripleArray = ^TRGBTripleArray;
  TRGBTripleArray = array[Word] of TRGBTriple;
var
  SL: PRGBTripleArray;
  y: Integer;
  x: Integer;
begin

  ABitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;

  for y := 0 to ABitmap.Height - 1 do
  begin
    SL := ABitmap.ScanLine[y];
    for x := 0 to ABitmap.Width - 1 do
      with SL[x] do
      begin
        rgbtRed := rgbtRed div 2;
        rgbtGreen := rgbtGreen div 2;
        rgbtBlue := rgbtBlue div 2;
      end;
  end;

end;
```

32 bits per pixel:

```pascal
procedure FadeBitmap32(ABitmap: TBitmap);
type
  PRGBQuadArray = ^TRGBQuadArray;
  TRGBQuadArray = array[Word] of TRGBQuad;
var
  SL: PRGBQuadArray;
  y: Integer;
  x: Integer;
begin

  ABitmap.PixelFormat := pf32bit;

  for y := 0 to ABitmap.Height - 1 do
  begin
    SL := ABitmap.ScanLine[y];
    for x := 0 to ABitmap.Width - 1 do
      with SL[x] do
      begin
        rgbRed := rgbRed div 2;
        rgbGreen := rgbGreen div 2;
        rgbBlue := rgbBlue div 2;
      end;
  end;

end;
```

This is a direct translation.

But both versions can be written more elegantly:

```
procedure FadeBitmap24(ABitmap: TBitmap);
begin

  ABitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;

  for var y := 0 to ABitmap.Height - 1 do
  begin
    var SL := PRGBTriple(ABitmap.ScanLine[y]);
    for var x := 0 to ABitmap.Width - 1 do
    begin
      SL.rgbtRed := SL.rgbtRed div 2;
      SL.rgbtGreen := SL.rgbtGreen div 2;
      SL.rgbtBlue := SL.rgbtBlue div 2;
      Inc(SL);
    end;
  end;

end;

procedure FadeBitmap32(ABitmap: TBitmap);
begin

  ABitmap.PixelFormat := pf32bit;

  for var y := 0 to ABitmap.Height - 1 do
  begin
    var SL := PRGBQuad(ABitmap.ScanLine[y]);
    for var x := 0 to ABitmap.Width - 1 do
    begin
      SL.rgbRed := SL.rgbRed div 2;
      SL.rgbGreen := SL.rgbGreen div 2;
      SL.rgbBlue := SL.rgbBlue div 2;
      Inc(SL);
    end;
  end;

end;
```